# Ansible AWS dynamic inventory connection not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, boto

I am trying to configure a server on AWS using ansible with a dynamic inventory script.

I created an ec2 instance which works fine and which I can manually ssh into. However, when trying to reach the instance (just to ping or to install software) I run into trouble.

```
ansible -i ec2.py all -m ping

xx.xx.xx.xx | FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"failed": true, 
"module_stderr": "Shared connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.\r\n", 
"module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", 
"msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
"rc": 0
```

}

and for

```
ansible-playbook deploy_site.yml -i ec2.py all

ERROR! the playbook: all could not be found
```

my all file lives in the directory group_vars

```
playbook
- deploy_site.yml
/group_vars
  -all
```

and looks like

```
ansible_user: ubuntu
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/key_pair.pem
```

my key_pair.pem file exists and with mod=600

All of this happens in a virtual environment specific ansible and both host and server are ubuntu 16.04.

Any thoughts on the reason for the connection problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible fails with /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429259/ansible-fails-with-bin-sh-1-usr-bin-python-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share the output of `ls /usr/bin/python*` and what is your `ansible` version.

Also try to install python and configure it on your `group_vars`:

```
apt-get install -y python-dev python3 python3-dev python3-setuptools
```

in your file try to do something like this:

```
ansible_user: ubuntu
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/key_pair.pem
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

you can also try :

```
ansible -i ec2.py all -m ping -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'
```

Comment: $ ls /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: which python
/home/mike/.pyenv/shims/python

Comment: ansible 2.3.0.0

Comment: @Mike did you tried to install the packages and follow my instructions ? also what is is the result of `ls /usr/bin/python*` ? to see all python versions on `/usr/bin` (you forgot the *)

Comment: ls /usr/bin/python 
/usr/bin/python            /usr/bin/python2-config  /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2           /usr/bin/python3         /usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2.7         /usr/bin/python3.5       /usr/bin/pythontex
/usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python3.5m      /usr/bin/pythontex3

Comment: so you have python on your local machine, can you check / install on the machine that you run the playbook and try again with my instruction, ansible_python_interpreter...

Comment: I now use python3 and this works with your instructions! Ubuntu 16.04 only has python3 installed on the server. Hence the ansible_python_interpreter...=python3 instruction makes the difference!

Answer (score 1):

The first problem:

> ```
> /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n"
> ```

You must have Python installed on the **target** machine as well as on the control machine.

---

The second problem:

> ```
> ansible-playbook deploy_site.yml -i ec2.py all
> ```

Remove `all` from the command.

With `ansible-playbook` you specify the target hosts inside the playbook with `hosts` directive.

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 does not have python2.7 installed anymore. Changing it to use the interpreter python3 did the trick for problem 1. Thanks for the pointer on problem 2! I mixed ansible and ansible-playbook commands.

Comment: Thats's exactly what I wrote: you need to install it. Mind that Python 3 support is experimental in Ansible and you might experience problems.