# Facing problems with ansible playbooks

Tags: python, ansible, devops

I am trying to learn ansible and starting to configure. After all configuration such as specifying the path for sshkey in group_vars and my makefile. I still somehow cannot succeed with the task.

Error Running ansible playbooks

When running `ansible-playbook provision_instances.yml` I get the following error. I seems that it is refusing connection to the localhost.

I ran make add-ssh after that I tried ansible-playbook provision_instances.yml

```
   `TASK [security_groups : Create Network Security Group]********************************************************************************************`


    The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_azure_rm_securitygroup_payload_vkggeut2/ansible_azure_rm_securitygroup_payload.zip/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 249, in <module>
    from azure.mgmt.privatedns import PrivateDnsManagementClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.mgmt.privatedns'
failed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] (item={'name': 'database', 'port_rules': [{'name': 'SSH', 'protocol': 'Tcp', 'destination_port_range': 22, 'access': 'Allow', 'priority': 1001, 'direction': 'Inbound', 'source_address_prefix': '0.0.0.0/0'}, {'name': 'MYSQL', 'protocol': 'Tcp', 'destination_port_range': 3306, 'access': 'Allow', 'priority': 1002, 'direction': 'Inbound', 'source_address_prefix': '0.0.0.0/0'}]}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "group",
    "changed": false,
    "group": {
        "name": "database",
        "port_rules": [
            {
                "access": "Allow",
                "destination_port_range": 22,
                "direction": "Inbound",
                "name": "SSH",
                "priority": 1001,
                "protocol": "Tcp",
                "source_address_prefix": "0.0.0.0/0"
            },
            {
                "access": "Allow",
                "destination_port_range": 3306,
                "direction": "Inbound",
                "name": "MYSQL",
                "priority": 1002,
                "protocol": "Tcp",
                "source_address_prefix": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "ad_user": null,
            "adfs_authority_url": null,
            "api_profile": "latest",
            "append_tags": true,
            "auth_source": "auto",
            "cert_validation_mode": null,
            "client_id": null,
            "cloud_environment": "AzureCloud",
            "default_rules": null,
            "location": null,
            "log_mode": null,
            "log_path": null,
            "name": "database-sg",
            "password": null,
            "profile": null,
            "purge_default_rules": false,
            "purge_rules": true,
            "resource_group": "DIDA-IDSA18-DV1617-H21-LP2",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "access": "Allow",
                    "description": null,
                    "destination_address_prefix": "*",
                    "destination_application_security_groups": null,
                    "destination_port_range": 22,
                    "direction": "Inbound",
                    "name": "SSH",
                    "priority": 1001,
                    "protocol": "Tcp",
                    "source_address_prefix": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "source_application_security_groups": null,
                    "source_port_range": "*"
                },
                {
                    "access": "Allow",
                    "description": null,
                    "destination_address_prefix": "*",
                    "destination_application_security_groups": null,
                    "destination_port_range": 3306,
                    "direction": "Inbound",
                    "name": "MYSQL",
                    "priority": 1002,
                    "protocol": "Tcp",
                    "source_address_prefix": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "source_application_security_groups": null,
                    "source_port_range": "*"
                }
            ],
            "secret": null,
            "state": "present",
            "subscription_id": null,
            "tags": {
                "StudentId": "idsa18"
            },
            "tenant": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on DESKTOP-BADTR07's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
}
```

Pip list gives me

```
adal                                  1.2.7
alembic                               1.7.5
ansible                               4.8.0
ansible-core                          2.11.7
applicationinsights                   0.11.10
argcomplete                           1.12.3
azure                                 4.0.0
azure-applicationinsights             0.1.0
azure-batch                           4.1.3
azure-cli-core                        2.26.1
azure-cli-telemetry                   1.0.6
azure-common                          1.1.11
azure-core                            1.21.1
azure-cosmosdb-nspkg                  2.0.2
azure-cosmosdb-table                  1.0.6
azure-datalake-store                  0.0.52
azure-eventgrid                       1.3.0
azure-graphrbac                       0.61.1
azure-identity                        1.7.0
azure-keyvault                        1.0.0a1
azure-keyvault-secrets                4.3.0
azure-loganalytics                    0.1.1
azure-mgmt                            4.0.0
azure-mgmt-advisor                    1.0.1
azure-mgmt-apimanagement              0.2.0
azure-mgmt-applicationinsights        0.1.1
azure-mgmt-authorization              0.51.1
azure-mgmt-automation                 0.1.1
azure-mgmt-batch                      5.0.1
azure-mgmt-batchai                    2.0.0
azure-mgmt-billing                    0.2.0
azure-mgmt-cdn                        3.0.0
azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices          3.0.0
azure-mgmt-commerce                   1.0.1
azure-mgmt-compute                    10.0.0
azure-mgmt-consumption                2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerinstance          1.4.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry          2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerservice           9.1.0
azure-mgmt-core                       1.2.2
azure-mgmt-cosmosdb                   0.5.2
azure-mgmt-datafactory                0.6.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics         0.6.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg             2.0.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-store             0.5.0
azure-mgmt-datamigration              1.0.0
azure-mgmt-devspaces                  0.1.0
azure-mgmt-devtestlabs                3.0.0
azure-mgmt-dns                        2.1.0
azure-mgmt-eventgrid                  1.0.0
azure-mgmt-eventhub                   2.0.0
azure-mgmt-hanaonazure                0.1.1
azure-mgmt-hdinsight                  0.1.0
azure-mgmt-iotcentral                 0.1.0
azure-mgmt-iothub                     0.7.0
azure-mgmt-iothubprovisioningservices 0.2.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault                   1.1.0
azure-mgmt-loganalytics               1.0.0
azure-mgmt-logic                      3.0.0
azure-mgmt-machinelearningcompute     0.4.1
azure-mgmt-managedservices            1.0.0
azure-mgmt-managementgroups           0.2.0
azure-mgmt-managementpartner          0.1.1
azure-mgmt-maps                       0.1.0
azure-mgmt-marketplaceordering        0.1.0
azure-mgmt-media                      1.0.1
azure-mgmt-monitor                    3.0.0
azure-mgmt-msi                        0.2.0
azure-mgmt-network                    12.0.0
azure-mgmt-notificationhubs           2.0.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg                      2.0.0
azure-mgmt-policyinsights             0.1.0
azure-mgmt-powerbiembedded            2.0.0
azure-mgmt-privatedns                 0.1.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms                      1.9.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservices           0.4.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup     0.6.0
azure-mgmt-redis                      5.0.0
azure-mgmt-relay                      0.1.0
azure-mgmt-reservations               0.2.1
azure-mgmt-resource                   10.2.0
azure-mgmt-scheduler                  2.0.0
azure-mgmt-search                     3.0.0
azure-mgmt-servicebus                 0.5.3
azure-mgmt-servicefabric              0.2.0
azure-mgmt-signalr                    0.1.1
azure-mgmt-sql                        0.10.0
azure-mgmt-storage                    11.1.0
azure-mgmt-subscription               0.2.0
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager             0.50.0
azure-mgmt-web                        0.41.0
azure-nspkg                           2.0.0
azure-servicebus                      0.21.1
azure-servicefabric                   6.3.0.0
azure-servicemanagement-legacy        0.20.7
azure-storage                         0.35.1
azure-storage-blob                    1.5.0
azure-storage-common                  1.4.2
azure-storage-file                    1.4.0
azure-storage-queue                   1.4.0
bcrypt                                3.2.0
boto                                  2.49.0
boto3                                 1.20.26
botocore                              1.23.26
certifi                               2021.10.8
cffi                                  1.15.0
chardet                               4.0.0
click                                 8.0.3
colorama                              0.4.4
cryptography                          3.3.2
dnspython                             2.1.0
dominate                              2.6.0
email-validator                       1.1.3
Flask                                 2.0.2
Flask-Bootstrap                       3.3.7.1
Flask-Login                           0.5.0
Flask-Migrate                         3.1.0
Flask-Moment                          1.0.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy                      2.5.1
Flask-WTF                             0.15.1
greenlet                              1.1.2
gunicorn                              20.1.0
humanfriendly                         9.2
idna                                  2.10
isodate                               0.6.1
itsdangerous                          2.0.1
Jinja2                                3.0.3
jmespath                              0.10.0
knack                                 0.8.2
Mako                                  1.1.6
MarkupSafe                            2.0.1
msal                                  1.16.0
msal-extensions                       0.3.1
msrest                                0.6.21
msrestazure                           0.6.4
oauthlib                              3.1.1
packaging                             21.3
paramiko                              2.9.1
pip                                   21.3.1
pkg_resources                         0.0.0
pkginfo                               1.8.2
portalocker                           1.7.1
psutil                                5.9.0
pycparser                             2.21
Pygments                              2.11.1
PyJWT                                 2.3.0
PyMySQL                               1.0.2
PyNaCl                                1.4.0
pyOpenSSL                             21.0.0
pyparsing                             3.0.6
python-dateutil                       2.8.2
python-dotenv                         0.19.1
PyYAML                                6.0
requests                              2.25.1
requests-oauthlib                     1.3.0
resolvelib                            0.5.4
s3transfer                            0.5.0
setuptools                            59.6.0
six                                   1.16.0
SQLAlchemy                            1.4.28
tabulate                              0.8.9
urllib3                               1.26.7
visitor                               0.1.3
Werkzeug                              2.0.2
WTForms                               3.0.0
xmltodict                             0.12.0
```

Comment: Set the no_log to false for debugging, the error could be anything.

Comment: [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) - [How to create a minimal complete verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70549472/edit) and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in the must read help article [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: @Zeitounator Is it better now? :)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429259/ansible-fails-with-bin-sh-1-usr-bin-python-not-found

Answer (score 2):

The `module_stderr` tells you that Ansible could not find the Python interpreter. You need to set this somewhere, for example in your inventory. Depending on your situation you may have to change the actual path. Should look something like this.

```
[groupname]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

You can also set it within the playbook itself by setting a variable.

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

  tasks:
    .....
```

Comment: Thanks this got me abit furthur but now I am facing a new issue `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.mgmt.privatedns'`. I have checked the package is present

Comment: Which packages did you install? You must have missed one or more.

Comment: I have updated the question with the list of packages I have installed. Kindly take a took, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which python interpreter are you using and which version of pip did you use to install the packages. They must be the same.